# Is "on how to use" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Here is my sentence. I feel that "on how to" seems incorrect.

Additionally, my technical skills were helpful in training customers on how to use the company's software.

Answer (score 4):

Grammatically valid, yes, but why don't you save yourself the space and doubt by using:

> Additionally, my technical skills were helpful in training customers to use the company's software.

There's no meaning change here, and you get extra points for succinctness!